# Question on how to stop my button click on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically, I am making a really basic python game for school and i am just trying to rush finish this as fast as I can, after `def RNG():` After I get the button to give me a random number, how do I stop the button for it? I can't spam click it.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master


root = Tk( )
app = Window(root)
root.title("BlackJack Game")
root.geometry("1920x1080+0+0")
root.configure(bg='gold')
lbl: Label = tkinter.Label(root, text='Welcome to Blackjack!', fg='steelblue', bg='gold1',
                           font=('arial', 50, "bold"))
lbl.pack()


def open():
    global top
    top = Toplevel()
    top.configure(bg='green')
    top.geometry("1920x1080+0+0")
    top.title('Game Window')
    lbl_1 = Label(top, text="BlackJack\n ", font=("arial", 75, "bold"), fg="black", bg="green").pack()
    root.withdraw()

    def RNG():
        import random
        x = random.randint(2, 21)
        lab = Label(top, text=x, font=("arial", 20, "bold"), fg="Black", bg='brown')
        lab.pack()

    global but
    but = Button(top, text='test', font=("arial", 20, "bold"), fg="Black", bg='brown', command=RNG, height=7, width=18).pack()    

work = Button(root, text="Press Play: ", font=("arial", 20, "bold"), fg="Black", bg='orange', command=open, ).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the button"? What does "spam click it" mean?

Comment: You can disable the button by `but.config(state='disabled')` inside `RNG()` function, but you need to separate the line `but = Button(top, text='test', ...).pack()` into two statements: `but = Button(...)` and `but.pack()`.

Comment: Also, you should try to avoid importing from inside your function. It's a good habit to put all our imports at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a few ways.

**First**: You can set the button's state to `disabled`

```
but = Button(top, text='test', state = DISABLED, font=("arial", 20, "bold"), fg="Black", bg='brown', command=RNG, height=7, width=18).pack()
```

or

```
but['state'] = DISABLED
```

Note that you should be disabling the button in the function it is calling. (for simplicity sake)

**Second**: You can redefine the button after and change the command it calls to '`" "`'

```
but = Button(top, text='test', state = DISABLED, font=("arial", 20, "bold"), fg="Black", bg='brown', command="", height=7, width=18).pack()
```

that way it cannot be spammed, it also means that when you call `open()` it should change the `but` button back to normal.